# Blender 2.77 Mac Installation-Python 3.5 files could not be opened

Tags: python, installation, osx

When unzipping the Blender 2.77 download file (blender-2.77-OSX_10.6-x86_64.zip) I get an error message "Could not extract the file 'blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.77/python/lib/python3.5/**pycache**/**future**.cpython-35.pyc': The file could not be opened".

If I click 'continue' I get a series of 'could not be opened' errors for what I assume is every file in the python 3.5 library.

I've not been able to find any information on this and don't see anywhere to ask about this at blender.org. I've not had this problem with previous installations of Blender.

I'm using a 2008 iMac running OSX Yosemite (10.10.5). Any thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend redownloading blender. I once (somehow) got a bad download, and blender would not start.

Comment: I took your suggestion and, after rebooting, I downloaded once from each of the 3 mirror sites but got the same error each time I tried to unzip the files.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that my problem was due to using an outdated version of The Unarchiver (version 1.0.1) to unzip the Blender 2.77a zip file. Upgrading OSX over the years did not upgrade this utility. Installing the most recent version of The Unarchiver from the App Store allowed me to unzip the Blender file normally with no error messages.